# Showing that $\sum_{n\in N}\sum_{k=0}^nu_kT^n=\sum_{k\in N}\sum_{l\in N}u_kT^{k+l}$

Tags: summation

We place ourselves in the ring of formal power series.

Let $(u_k)$ be a family of natural integers.

How do I prove **rigorously** the following equality ?

$$\sum_{n\in N}\sum_{k=0}^nu_kT^n=\sum_{k\in N}\sum_{l\in N}u_kT^{k+l}$$

This is taken from a correction of an exam.

I am guessing the equality is not true because

$$\sum_{n\in N}\sum_{k=0}^nu_kT^n=\sum_{n\in N}(T^n\sum_{k=0}^nu_k)$$ but

$$\sum_{k\in N}\sum_{l\in N}u_kT^{k+l}=\sum_{k\in N}(T^k\sum_{l\in N}u_kT^{l})$$

Comment: What have you tried, what tools do you have available to use, and where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I changed the title into a more informative one. I hope it is acceptable.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad explanation. English is not my first language and this is my first post on this website.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Thanks for editing your question!

Answer (score 1):

They will be equal if the coefficient of $T^n$ is the same for all $n$.

So on the one hand, on the left side, the coefficient of $T^n$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n u_k$.

On the other hand, the right hand side is $ \displaystyle \sum_l \sum_k u_k T^{l+k}$.What we're interested in is the case when $l+k = n$, so that we compute and compare the $T^n$th coefficient. For each $k$ such there is is a solution to $l+k=n$, we will get the term $u_k$ in the sum of the coefficients. Fortunately, the solutions to $l+k=n$ are easy to see, and start $l=n,k=0$, then $l=n-1, k = 1$, $\ldots$, $l=0, k=n$. So for every $k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$, we include $u_k$ in the coefficient, and moreover these are all the coefficients. Thus the coefficient of $T^n$ is exactly $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n u_k$.

Written more succinctly,

$$\sum_l \sum_k u_k T^{l+k} = \sum_n \sum_{l+k = n} u_k T^n = \sum_n \sum_{k = 0}^n u_k T^n,$$

where I collected the terms $l+k = n$ and summed over all possible $l,k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $l+k=n$, and then realized that $l$ appears nowhere so there's no need to include it in the computation.

Comment: Really appreciated. Thank you very much.